# eclipse force exception feature

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception

Eclipse has a nice feature Force return. I wonder if it has Force exception, so I can manually throw exception at current execution point?

Any other workaround if eclipse lacks this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Eclipse's [conditional breakpoint](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F) feature to do this. You can [execute arbitrary code](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19825.html) in a breakpoint condition.

Answer (score 2):

In display view, execute: {throw new AnyKindOfException();}
Check [here for more eclipse tips and trick](http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2016/02/eclipse-tips-trick-2016.html)